# Change the name of images at run time according to record and then display them in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a problem regarding Changing name of images at run time and after that i wanna show the images. Pleas read below :

I've two pages in my web application **(state.aspx and images.aspx)**.  On state page i have listed all states. 
suppose **newyork** is state and when i clicked on **newyork**. It goes to **images.aspx** page with a **querystring** with name of state.

Now i want to change the name of all images on **"images.aspx"** page according to selected State.

**for example - myimage.jpg  to myimage-newyork.jpg**

Now the main problem is, if i'll change the name of images. There should exist the images with same name.

**How can i do this?**

Comment: Classic ASP is NOT asp.net - please don't use that tag.

Comment: Are you changing the src of the images or just the name.  You can add the images dynamically at runtime or you can change then client side with JavaScript.

Comment: I think we need more information.  Are you changing the names of the images in your image store?  Is this a one-time thing you need to do or something you'll do every time the web app is run?  Or are you changing what you display about the images?

Comment: @BrianP If i'll change the name of image then it should exist in the specified folder. So i have to change name of stored images in a directory and have to show on page.

Comment: @AnnL. Its simnple, When ever a user click on a state(lots of states are there), then name of the images will change on next page. and it should change the name of images in directory. So that image src can find the images...  is this information sufficient??

Answer (score 0):

It has been a little while since I have done this, but I believe what you want to do is change the headers:

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","myimage.jpg"));
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

Comment: Also a lot of people prefer to use httphandlers these days instead of serving it through the aspx. Here is a quick example:

http://worldofasp.net/tut/images/Displaying_images_in_ASPNET_using_HttpHandlers_92.aspx

I generally will do something like that but map a path to a *.jpg, that way it even looks like an image if you copied the url.

Comment: I'm not getting you at all. I got this link http://saradesh.com/tajuddin/index.php/rename-files-in-file-directory-using-asp-net/
I want to do something like this. but it won't work, when there are lots of user on application.